# Jquery Treetable issues with internet explorer 6

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer

Jquery treetable component is giving performance issues with internet explorer 6 .   It takes a lot of time loading the tree and some time it even halts . Is there any way to improve the performance or is there any better component that gives the same functionality and is compatible with ie6 . Any help would be greatly appreciated Thanks!

Comment: Probably not the answer you are looking for but why are you supporting IE6? IE6 should have died a long time ago but people keep it alive by trying to support it (wasting time, money and energy). Even MS themselves have abandoned it. I do understand however that clients can force this upon developers but this really is the client's issue. The more dev's that say NO to IE6 the quicker it can rest in peace and be forgotten. (sorry for the rant)

Comment: Some industrial environment you "have to" support IE6, for legacy drivers and equipment. This is a nice try to send IE6 to grave, but e.g. a factory not throw away any machinery for nicer browsers. :(

Comment: Yea you are rite I figured out the problem and had to develop a custom tree component without the recursion . Recursion was the main issue that made the jquery tree component halt . Inorder to solve that problem i had to come up with an iterative solution . Bingo !!